# Python csv/excel convert single column to multiple rows

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like below, and I need to convert this to multple rows either in an excel or a csv format

```
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Address1</th>
<th>City</th>
<th>State</th>
<th>Zip</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>John</th>
<th>111 Michigan</th>
<th>Chicago </th>
<th>IL</th>
<th>60661</th>
</tr>
```

Desired result:

```
Name   Address1       City   State  Zip
John  111 Michigan   Chicago  IL    60661
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse the HTML and for every row print the column values.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using beautifulSoup4, but I am able to only get the first row as my result. The rest if the rows are coming as blank

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("CofATX.txt"))
table = soup.find('table')

rows = table.findAll('tr')

for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('th')
for th in cols:
    text = ''.join(th.text.strip())
    print text + "|",
print
```

The result I am getting is 
    Name | Address1 | City | State | Zip
The rest if the rows are blank

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. FYI, this is not a forum or a chat. What you have tried **should be in your your question**. Please copy it over and delete this non-answer.

Answer (score 0):

I might use the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) library for this.  You can turn the table into a `DataFrame` (kind of like an Excel sheet), although we'll have to add `<table>` markings because they're missing from your text:

```
import pandas as pd
with open("name.html") as fp:
    text = fp.read()

df = pd.read_html("<table>" + text + "</table>", infer_types=False)[0]
```

which gives us

```
>>> df
      0             1        2      3      4
0  Name      Address1     City  State    Zip
1  John  111 Michigan  Chicago     IL  60661
```

which we can save as a `csv` file:

```
>>> df.to_csv("out.csv", sep="|", index=False, header=False)
```

giving

```
Name|Address1|City|State|Zip
John|111 Michigan|Chicago|IL|60661
```

or save directly as an Excel file:

```
>>> df.to_excel("out.xlsx")
```

`pandas` is my go-to tool for data munging.